# Probability Mass Function for a Random Variable

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

My Question reads: 
Suppose a random variable Y has the probability mass function
f$_Y$ (i) = r$^i$ with i=2,3,4,.... Find r.

I was thinking of setting up a sum because we know the sum of the pmf must be equal to 1. However, I am unsure how to continue or this will be somehow an infinite geometric series.

Comment: It will be an infinite geometric series. You just need to make substitution, because in your case this series starts from $i=2$. To use the basic formula for the sum of geometric series you would propably like to start from $i=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty r^k=r^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k.
$$

Comment: Well, we would be starting like r$^2$+ r$^3$+.... and so on, then would I need to sort of work with this to get what I need?

Comment: That's exactly the left hand side of the identity.

Comment: Ignore the $r^2$ for now, sum up the series on the right (which should be trivial for you, since now it's just the geometric series just as you know it). When you're done, recall that you left $r^2$, so multiply the sum by this factor. Compare it to 1 and calculate $r$ from quadratic equation and you're done.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Jack okay, got it! But I have two answers for my r since I did need the quadratic formula, then would I need to just pick the positive one in this case?

Comment: Well, one must have $F_y(i)\geq 0$ for all $i$. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, wow, I completely forgot for a moment that I was dealing with probabilities. Okay the positive it is, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

$$
1=\sum_{n\ge 2}r^n=\frac{r^2}{1-r} \implies (2r+1)^2-5=0 \implies r=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}.
$$